# Is it possible to skip admin password when running program as administrator on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10

I have upgraded to windows 10, and I have set my microsoft account. Since then, whenever I try to run program as an administrator, I am forced to enter an admin password every time. I don't want to enter password every time I try to do something with admin permission, and I couldn't find any options to disable it. Is it possible? If yes, where is it?

Comment: Either make the account an admin account, or remove the password.

Comment: I am using the admin account, yet I see it.

Comment: @revi - You are suppose to see it.  The UAC prompt is the equivalent of `sudo` in the linux world.  You cannot fully disable UAC in Windows 8 and above, if you do set it to the lowest settings, the net result is the Windows Store applications will stop working.  This means that programs like `Calculator` in Windows 10 will stop working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### I am logged in as an Admin account but UAC prompts for a password. How do I change this?

There are a number of different security levels under Local Security Policy that can be selected. It's possible you are on `Prompt for Credentials`. To change this:

1. Hit the `Start` and type `Local Security Policy` (Or enter `secpol.msc` under `Run` - <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>)
2. Navigate to `Local Policies` -> `Security Options`. In the list, find the policy `User Account Control: Behavior of the elevation prompt for administrators in Admin Approval Mode`

[image]

3. Double click this. You'll have a dropdown box of options. For a normal `Yes` and `No` prompt, choose `Prompt for consent`

You should now get this prompt

[image]

... instead of this...

[image]

You could also choose `Elevate without prompting`, but you may as well disable UAC with this enabled.

Comment: Hi. Is this possible for Windows 7/8.1?

Comment: @CJL - Yes, it is available for Windows 7 onwards. I think it was also available on Vista... but who uses Vista lol!

Comment: @CJL Yes, this should work in those also. To get there, use secpol.msc under Run - Win + R

Comment: Btw, Local Security Policy is only available in Win 10 Pro.

Answer (score 1):

For those who aren't running Windows 10 Pro and don't have the Group Policy Editor and **`secpol.msc`** on their system, you can [achieve the same effect](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd835564(v=ws.10).aspx) by modifying **`ConsentPromptBehaviorAdmin`** DWORD under **`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System`**

Navigate to the key using `regedit.exe` (<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> → `regedit` → <kbd>Enter</kbd>)

The available values are:

```
0 = Elevate without prompting
1 = Prompt for credentials on the secure desktop
2 = Prompt for consent on the secure desktop
3 = Prompt for credentials
4 = Prompt for consent
5 (Default) = Prompt for consent for non-Windows binaries
```

Change the value of **`ConsentPromptBehaviorAdmin`** to **5** for default behavior.